# Python lookup folder to import modules

Tags: python, module

two py file:

### ./src/foo.py

```
def bar ():
    print 'bar!'
```

### ./tests/testfoo.py

```
from foo import bar
print 'testing'
bar ()
```

in the root folder './', calling

```
python ./tests/testfoo.py
```

the result is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tests/testfoo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from foo import bar
ImportError: No module named foo
```

running the testfoo.py but naturally module foo could not be found by the interpreter. can i give any parameter to interpreter to lookup modules in the folder 'src'?

## Edit #1

also added two empty **init**.py file.

```
./src/__init__.py
./tests/__init__.py
```

still getting the same error.

## Edit #2 (Solution)

I solved problem by adding a new initialization py file

## prep.py

```
import os, sys
cur = os.path.dirname (__file__)
pathtest = os.path.join (cur, 'tests')
sys.path.append (pathtest)
```

then called:

```
python prep.py tests/testfoo.py
```

it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('your/path')
import testfoo
```

You may need to make `./tests` an absolute path...

Comment: i'm not looking for this. i should solve with the interpreter in command line

Comment: @jacklondon: (love the name) You will still need to tell Python where the file is. Python cannot deal with paths other than as part of the PYTHONPATH which you can change in the shell or in the script. I (personally) prefer to leave the shell alone unless it is a longer-term change.

Answer (score 4):

The environment variable PYTHONPATH keeps the search paths for Python modules.  For example

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/username/lib/python2.6/site-packages:/usr/local/stsci_python/lib/python:
```

Modify this to add your directory:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/your/new/path"
```

(This is on BASH, by the way.)

Answer (score 1):

Put a `__init__.py` in those directories to indicate to python that they should be treated like packages.

```
./src/__init__.py
./tests/__init__.py
```

This will fix the issue from the location you are running it, since python will check the current directory. But it will not fix the issue if you were to run it from some random location like:

```
/some/other/path/ $ /projects/tests/testfoo.py
```

What you need is to modify your PYTHONPATH to include that location:

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/projects
```

This can be added to either your shell environment, or done manually each time.

Comment: added init files, but python did not find the modules as i expected.